# Bit manipulator (reader / writer)

Tags: c++, bitwise

Please take a review of my simple bit manipulator:

```
#ifndef BIT_STREAM_H
#define BIT_STREAM_H

#include <cstdint>

class BitStream {
public:
    explicit BitStream(uint8_t* buffer, size_t buffer_size) : m_Buffer(buffer), m_BufferSize(buffer_size) {

    }

    virtual ~BitStream() = default;

public:
    inline uint64_t Mask(uint64_t offset, size_t size) const {
        return ((1 << size) - 1) << offset;
    }

public:
    inline size_t GetBufferSize() const {
        return m_BufferSize;
    }

    inline size_t GetOffset() const {
        return m_Offset;
    }

    inline bool GetErrorState() const {
        return m_ErrorState;
    }

protected:
    uint8_t* m_Buffer = nullptr;
    size_t m_BufferSize = 0;
    size_t m_Offset = 0;
    bool m_ErrorState = false;
};

class BitReader : public BitStream {
public:
    explicit BitReader(uint8_t* buffer, size_t buffer_size) : BitStream(buffer, buffer_size) {

    }

    template <size_t buffer_size>
    explicit BitReader(uint8_t(&buffer)[buffer_size]) : BitStream(buffer, buffer_size) {

    }

public:
    template<const size_t bit_size, typename value_t = uint64_t>
    inline value_t Read(value_t df = 0) {
        const size_t bpb = 8;
        const size_t byte_offset = m_Offset / bpb;
        const size_t relative_offset = m_Offset - (byte_offset * bpb);

        if (m_ErrorState) {
            return df;
        }

        if (((m_Offset + bit_size) / bpb) >= m_BufferSize) {
            m_ErrorState = true;
            return df;
        }

        m_Offset += bit_size;

        return (*(value_t*)&m_Buffer[byte_offset] & Mask(relative_offset, bit_size)) >> relative_offset;
    }
};

class BitWriter : public BitStream {
public:
    explicit BitWriter(uint8_t* buffer, size_t buffer_size) : BitStream(buffer, buffer_size) {

    }

    template <size_t buffer_size>
    explicit BitWriter(uint8_t(&buffer)[buffer_size]) : BitStream(buffer, buffer_size) {

    }

public:
    template<const size_t bit_size, typename value_t = uint64_t>
    inline void Write(value_t value) {
        const size_t bpb = 8;
        const size_t byte_offset = m_Offset / bpb;
        const size_t relative_offset = m_Offset - (byte_offset * bpb);

        if (m_ErrorState) {
            return;
        }

        if (((m_Offset + bit_size) / bpb) >= m_BufferSize) {
            m_ErrorState = true;
            return;
        }

        m_Offset += bit_size;

        *(value_t*)&m_Buffer[byte_offset] = (*(value_t*)&m_Buffer[byte_offset] & ~Mask(relative_offset, bit_size)) | (value << relative_offset);
    }
};

#endif // BIT_STREAM_H
```

Example of usage:

```
#include "BitStream.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    uint8_t buffer[2];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    BitWriter writer(buffer);

    writer.Write<4>(15);
    writer.Write<2>(0);
    writer.Write<6>(63);

    assert(!writer.GetErrorState());

    BitReader reader(buffer);

    std::cout << reader.Read<4>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << reader.Read<2>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << reader.Read<6>() << std::endl;

    assert(!reader.GetErrorState());

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Later in plan add exceptions, to string converter method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Unnecessary use of template arguments

In the functions `BitReader::Read()` and `BitWrite::Write()`, the `bit_size` should just be a normal function argument instead of a template argument:

```
template<typename value_t>
void Write(size_t bit_size, value_t value) {
    ...
}

...

writer.Write(4, 15);
```

## Restrict the allowed value types to integers

You currently allow any type for `value_t`. This can be problematic though. What happens if I do:

```
writer.Write(4, 3.1415);
```

Or something like:

```
int a = 15;
writer.Write(4, &a);
```

Either explicitly restrict the allowed types to integers using [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
template <typename value_t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<value_t>::value>::type>
void Write(size_t bit_size, value_t value) {
    ...
}
```

Or don't use template at all, and just use `uint64_t` unconditionally, and rely on implicit casts between different size integers:

```
void Write(size_t bit_size, uint64_t value) {
    ...
}
```

## Use `memcpy()` to avoid unaligned reads and writes

The following code has undefined behavior in C++, and might cause crashes on platforms that do not allow unaligned reads and writes to memory:

```
*(value_t *)&m_Buffer[byte_offset]
```

Apart from the alignment issue, the above statement might cause data to be read or written beyond the end of `m_Buffer`.

The correct way to do this is to use `memcpy()` to move data from the buffer into a `value_t` variable, and when moving data from a `value_t` variable to the buffer. While that might seem less optimal, the compiler will most likely be able to convert it back to an unaligned read or write on platforms that support it. So for example in `Read()`, you should write something like:

```
value_t value = 0;
memcpy(&value, &m_Buffer[byte_offset], std::min(sizeof value, m_BufferSize - byte_offset));
value &= Mask(relative_offset, bit_size);
value >>= relative_offset;
return value;
```

Instead of updating `m_Buffer()` directly in every call to `Read()` and `Write()`, you can also consider having a `uint64_t` staging buffer. For example, in `Write()`, you can add bits to the staging buffer until it is full, and then copy the staging buffer into `m_Buffer`, advance `byte_offset` by `sizeof(uint64_t)` and then continue from an empty staging buffer.

## Consider big-endian platforms

Your code assumes that integers are stored in little-endian format. If you need to support big-endian platforms, then your code is not correct.

## Consider asserting that the `value` does not exceed the given `bit_size`

You might want to assert that the `value` passed to `Write()` fits in the given `bit_size`. You could throw an exception if it doesn't, or just add an `assert()` statement that helps debugging but doesn't impact performance on release builds:

```
void Write(size_t bit_size, uint64_t value) {
    assert(bit_size <= 8 * sizeof value);
    assert(bit_size == 8 * sizeof value || value >> bit_size == 0);
    ...
}
```

## Shifting `uint64_t` by 64 is undefined behavior

In C++, you can only reliably shift a value by up to `8 * sizeof(value) - 1` bits. That means you cannot shift an `uint64_t` by 64. Currently, your code has undefined behavior if you `Read()` or `Write()` 64 bits in one go.

## Reading or writing more than 57 bits at a time might fail

Your code does not handle reading or writing more than 57 bits at a time correctly. Consider that `Mask()` generates a bitmask for the given `size`, and then shifts it by `offset`. Depending on what value came before it, `offset` can be between 0 and 7. So if `offset` is 7 and you want to write a 58-bit value to the buffer, you get a mask larger than an `uint64_t` can hold.

## Unnecessary use of `inline`

Member functions that are defined inside a class declaration are automatically `inline`, so there is no need to specify that explicitly.

## Avoid `std::endl`

You should use [`\n` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n). The latter is equivalent to `\n`, but forces a flush of the output stream, which can be bad for performance.

Comment: _bit_size should just be a normal function argument instead of a template argument_ - Really? What is your justification? If there is a small and well-known set of sizes, the compiler will be better able to produce optimized code.

Comment: @Reinderien: The functions are inlined anyway, so the compiler can optimize it regardless of whether it is a template argument or a normal function argument.

Answer (score 4):

### Inline isn't

This pops up on CodeReview regularly. `inline` is effectively ignored by most modern compilers, and even if it weren't, it isn't a good idea to force the matter -- programmers do not know what's best for their program when compared to the compiler when full optimization is enabled. It's safe to omit this.

### Redundant initial values

```
uint8_t* m_Buffer = nullptr;
size_t m_BufferSize = 0;
```

These are initialized by your constructor, so there's no point in pre-initializing them here.

### Type punning

This:

```
*(value_t*)&m_Buffer[byte_offset]
```

is a little gross. There are better ways to do inline pointer casts, particularly in C++. Here, since you're punning from `uint8_t*` to a pointer of arbitrary type, you'll probably want `reinterpret_cast`.

I guess `bit_size` should be 64 if you pass `uint64_t` for `value_t`, but I don't see why it's passed separately. You can move `bpb` up in scope; then `bit_size` would equal `bpb * sizeof(value_t)`. Perhaps you want to support `bit_size` smaller than the value type, which is fine; but you should at least assert that `bit_size` is less than or equal to the number of bits in `value_t`.

There are subtler risks in the way that you're packing bits - from what I can tell, it assumes little-endian, which will not be universally true.

Comment: inline is not ignored, it allows different compilation units to redefine the function with exactly same body, and potentially, optimize by combining to a single implementation at the linking time.

Comment: for my personal point, it is not redundant initial, but default, for comfortable expand class in future, I not like worries about it each time when adding new construction method, and in this nothing bad for compile or run time, in current case m_Buffer & m_BufferSize will be initialized only once a time - in the defined constructor. [proof](https://i.imgur.com/ZrlnrGa.png)